# MySQL creating a rounded timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I just got stuck on one SQL query, where I need to create a timestamp with certain parts re-set.

I'll be needing to add interval of 30 minutes on one query and 6 hours on second query. However, the rest of the time should be 0.
Example,
I have the following datetime: `2013-07-04 00:04:57` And I want to add 30 minutes, what I need it to be is: `2013-07-04 00:34:00`. Same goes to adding the hours, if I had the same time and added 6 hours, I'd need to get: `2013-07-04 06:00:00` instead of `2013-07-04 06:04:57`.

I was experimenting with `TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 6, UTC_TIMESTAMP())`, but I couldn't find a way to "round" the minutes/seconds. Additionally, I have been experimenting with: `MAKETIME(HOUR(UTC_TIMESTAMP()), MINUTE(ADDTIME(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), '0:30:0')),0)` which works pretty well, except that the date part is missing.

Can you please help me solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using `date_format()` and only specifying the parts you want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `now()` with any datetime you want to alter:

```
DATE_ADD(
  DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00"),
  INTERVAL(30 + (IF(SECOND(now()) > 29, 1, 0))) MINUTE
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience is with T-SQL primarily, but I'd solve this with something like:

```
SELECT DATEADD(millisecond, -(DATEPART(millisecond, @myDate)), DATEADD(second, -(DATEPART(second, @myDate)), DATEADD(minute, -(DATEPART(minute, @myDate) % 30), DATEADD(minute, 30, @myDate))))
```

Essentially adding a half-hour first, deducting the remaining minutes modulo 30, deducting the seconds and then the milliseconds.

But I don't think the DATEPART function is available to you. A brief look at [the spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_microsecond) and I see equivalent functions like MINUTE(), SECOND(), MICROSECOND() which should work similarly.